# Registration by convention and interception causes ResolutionFailedException

Tags: unity-container, unity-interception

Simple scenario

```
public interface IFoo
{
   int GetData();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    [CacheResult]
    public int GetData() { .... }
}

public class MyController
{
    [Dependency]
    IFoo Foo {get; set;}
}
```

If I register the interface manually, resolving MyController works fine:

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>(),
    new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>());

var controller = container.Resolve<MyController>();
```

If I try to use auto-registration:

```
        container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default,
            WithLifetime.ContainerControlled,
            getInjectionMembers: t => new InjectionMember[]
            {
                new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(),
                new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>(),
            });

var controller = container.Resolve<MyController>();
```

The resolve fails with a ResolutionFailedException because the Type passed must be an interface. Of course, if I make it an interface, it will work, but only if it is named Controller. If I call it, MyController or SqlController or whatever, then the mapping fails because it cannot resolve the interface.

I was hoping to just do an assembly scan, similar to what the Spring framework does, but I have not been able to figure it out.

What am I missing? Or is this not possible in Unity?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies is matching and registering your controller as well.  Then when Unity tries to resolve the controller (not IFoo), it finds that the *controller* is not registered with an interface.

Here's a helper that will reduce your registrations to only those classes that have a matching interface.

```
public static class TypeFilters
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> WithMatchingInterface(this IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        return types.Where(type => 
            type.GetTypeInfo().GetInterface("I" + type.Name) != null);
    }
}
```

and then you can use this to modify your registration like so...

```
AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().WithMatchingInterface()
```